# C++ Error Handling

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch, user-input

Is it possible to know if command, started by `system(cCmdInput);` failed, and show an error, if it does.

```
cout << endl << "Enter command> ";
getline(cin, cmdInput);
try{
    cin.clear();
    const char *cCmdInput = cmdInput.c_str();
    system(cCmdInput);
}catch (...){
    cout << "An error occurred";
}
```

Comment: How do you expect this message to be helpful?  Don't write code like this.  That also includes the horrific indenting you use.

Comment: @close-voters: most likely the OP wants to know how to detect, via use of `system`, whether the process succeeded or failed. In practice that isn't hard for a well-behaved process in *nix or Windows. Voted to re-open (and please don't be so fast on the trigger finger: you could reasonably have waited a few second to let the OP explain).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should not be using `system()` as it is a big security risk (especially when using input from the user like in your code above). Rather, take a look at the `exec()` family of functions.

But to answer your question, `system()` does not throw any exceptions. You need to check what it returns. [According to the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/), it will generally return the status code of the command you ran. You need to look up the return codes for the command you're using and check the value `system()` returns against those. Generally, a return value of 0 means success though.

For example:

```
if(system(cCmdInput) != 0)
   cout << "Error" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`system` is a C function, and do not throw exceptions. Instead, it returns a value, that can be used to interpret, if execution succeeded.

According to [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [documantation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system),

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g. fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.

Usually return status `0` indicates success.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, in *nix and Windows, the `system` function will return the process exit code of the program you ran.

So, for running a well-behaved program, just check if the result is 0 or not. By convention process exit code 0 means success, and any other value means failure.

Note however that many Windows programs are not well-behaved in the sense of producing an error-indicating process exit code. You can check this in the Windows command interpreter, most directly by `echo %errorlevel%` after running the program. Another way is to use the logical connectives `&&` and `||`, e.g. `myprog && echo OK || echo Bah, failed!`.